# How to publish a standalone script to run as a cron job?

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I'm new to Google Apps Scripts, and I'm working on a script that runs as a user and looks through a shared Drive folder and updates file properties based on user-specific file properties (i.e. "starred" and "trashed"). I've created a standalone script that will do this, and set a project trigger to run the job every hour. This works for the developer account.

I deployed as a web app (despite no need for a GUI), and tried to install it using the web app URL logged in as a different user. All this seemed to do was request user access to the script .gs file (in which the trigger created in the developer account was not visible). Are these triggers user-specific?

How do I get this script installed on multiple user accounts (with their authorization) so that it just runs at regular intervals set by the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Installable triggers are not user specific and will always run under the authorization of their creator.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who
>   created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger,
>   it will run when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague
>   has edit access), but it will run as your account. This means that if
>   you create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the
>   email will always be sent from your account, not necessarily the
>   account that opened the document. However, you could create an
>   installable trigger for each account, which would result in one email
>   sent from each account.

If you want them to run under multiple users accounts, then those users need to setup their own installable triggers on that script under their accounts.

Comment: OK, but I think it's a time trigger rather than an installable trigger.

Comment: @CynthiaWarren A time-driven trigger is an installable trigger. Please refer to the documentation for [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have referred to the documentation. Do you have any thoughts on how I can get the script installed and running for multiple users? Is the only way to share the script file and ask each user to manually create the trigger?

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically create the installable trigger as the user? For example, if I publish as a web app, could I create a button to click which would get the required authorizations and create the trigger for the user? Is that possible?

Comment: @CynthiaWarren Yes, each user needs top install their own trigger, and yes you can programmatically install triggers. The installable triggers documentation linked above provides details on how to programmatically manipulate triggers. If need be, ask that as a new question to make it more available to SO users, if the above answer answers your original question mark it as answered.